# Até onde devemos traduzir as palavras e termos?

Tags: debate, idioma

Uma questão que fico em dúvida é até onde devemos nos preocupar em traduzir palavras e termos?

Acho legal a iniciativa de se disponibilizar um sistema em português, mas diferente do nativo oriundo de Portugal, o brasileiro contém muitas palavras em inglês de forma popular assim como palavras "aportuguesadas", tais como:

- **Debugar**: que é a ação de depurar
- **Popular**: apesar de ter significado em português diferente, normalmente se refere quando um programador está povoando sua base de dados, foi uma mistura com a palavra americana *populate*
- **Sortear**: ação de ordenar, ou aplicar um *sort*

Repare que na palavra *debugar*, não há  em português, por tanto é fácil deduzir seu significado, já em *popular* apesar de existir homônimo, no caso alguém que tem popularidade ou é muito conhecido, seu contexto acaba se tornando claro com certa facilidade.

Já a palavra *sortear* tem um homônimo em português com significado totalmente diferente, onde seria o intuito de embaralhar algo.

Devemos ser criteriosos a ponto de eliminar essas palavras comuns porém com significado duvidoso quando mal empregadas, focando na coerência e coesão?

Seria também parte do processo traduzir palavras e termos conhecidos como *debug* para *depurador*, *array* para *matriz* e assim por diante?

Comment: Utilizar a palavra `sortear` com o sentido de ordenação é **homicídio doloso e duplamente qualificado** do idioma português, ok? Eu mesmo só a vi nesse sentido pela primeira vez aqui no *SOpt*. Meus colegas de profissão têm historicamente usado o verbo `ordenar` para isso ;)

Comment: @Renan concordo plenamente, assim como não gosto de usar *debugar* apesar de ser compreensivo eu já torço o nariz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não acho que exista uma resposta única para o "até onde", é preciso discutir caso a caso. Isso é mais importante no caso das tags. Nas perguntas e respostas, basta que haja clareza e que as pessoas se entendam.

Minhas opiniões sobre cada um dos seus exemplos:

- **Debugar**
  Eu acho bem natural, porém temos uma tag [depuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depura%c3%a7%c3%a3o) que não sei se tem tradução/sinônimo melhor. Debugamento? Debugação? Debugging mesmo? O próprio debugger eu prefiro chamar de debugger do que debugador ou depurador.
- **Popular**
  O termo já está mais do que consagrado entre os programadores, todo mundo entende. Qualquer ambiguidade com os homônimos (o verbo e o ajetivo) é facilmente resolvida pelo contexto.
- **Sortear**
  Não gosto do uso no sentido de ordernar, acho que confuso. Eu prefiro sempre usar no sentido de "escolher uma ou mais opções aleatoriamente". Não sei se temos tags para ambos os sentidos, mas poderíamos ter [ordenação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordena%c3%a7%c3%a3o), e [sorteio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorteio) ou [aleatório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aleat%c3%b3rio).
- **array**
  Sou a favor de usar *array* mesmo. A melhor tradução depende da linguagem, ou mesmo do uso da array dentro de uma linguagem. Às vezes é um vetor, às vezes é uma matriz, às vezes é uma lista, às vezes é um dicionário...

Comment: +1 Eu concordo com a sua opinião, mas acho que o stackoverflow sendo um local de pluralização do conhecimento, talvez seja interessante um manifesto para re-educar os desenvolvedores, ao menos em sua leitura/escrita formal, corrigindo termos americanizados, colocando seus equivalentes em português e talvez em alguns casos em inglês mesmo como termos referente ao código em si, como caso do *array*. As perguntas e respostas perdurariam aos vícios de linguagem cotidianos por mais tempo.

Comment: Concordo com o uso de `Array`. Dá pra saber se o cara aprendeu o "B A BA" na faculdade ou se ele entende por conta própria se ele fala Vetor ou Array, respectivamente. Array é muito mais utilizado no meio profissional e Vetor APENAS no meio acadêmico.
`Sortear` nunca vi sendo usando para ordenar. E `debugar` é misturar linguagens, ou `debug` ou `depurar`, `debugar` dói.

Answer (score 5):

A ideia do SOPT é criar um lugar onde os desenvolvedores lusófonos possam interagir, sem o atrito e o fardo de ter que escrever em outra língua. Então o objetivo principal é que todos se entendam.

Nossa área é repleta de neologismos, anglicismos e outras artimanhas linguísticas, adquiridas ao longo de anos de contato direto com a língua inglesa. Nem todas essas expressões novas são amplamente adotadas e o que é comum para um determinado grupo de pessoas pode soar estranho para outros, mas eu acredito que seria muito raro alguém usar uma expressão que fosse realmente *incompreensível*.

Em um local criado justamente para facilitar a interação, tentar definir quais expressões devem ser usadas é criar dificuldades à toa. Além disso, abre margem para que haja um debate sobre todas as expressões que alguém acreditar que devem, ou não devem, ser utilizadas no site. Vamos usar *browser ou navegador*? *Array ou lista*? O debate é interminável e iria de encontro ao propósito dessa comunidade.

Se você discorda de alguém usar *sortear* mas conseguiu entender o sentido, deixe estar. Não é isso que determina a qualidade do post. Se o post é realmente difícil de se entender, peça que o autor esclareça o que quis dizer, ou até mesmo edite direto.

Comment: "Nossa área é repleta de neologismos, anglicismos (...) adquiridas ao longo de anos de contato direto com a língua inglesa" Minha única crítica é que em geral isso é consequência da falta de compreensão do inglês. Quem sabe que "sort" significa "ordenar" vai pensar em "ordenar", quem só viu um método `sort` e quer "aplicar o `sort` à minha lista" vai acabar chegando em "sortear". Não fazer nada a respeito é permitir que a desinformação persista (mas concordo que não cabe aqui uma intervenção nos posts alheios, melhor "ensinar pelo exemplo" - i.e. usar termos mais adequados nos próprios posts).

Comment: Em muitos casos, array e lista (list) não são sinônimos. O mesmo vale pra várias palavras usadas em inglês que não tem uma tradução boa em português.

Comment: Consigo viver com pessoas escrevendo termos em inglês... Acho de difícil entendimento que misturem as duas linguagens.

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com a resposta do **bfavaretto** - não é possível e nem desejável generalizar o caso para todos os termos.

Cada caso é um caso. Vou fazer minha própria análise dos termos citados também.

- **Debugar:** acho que metade dos programadores com quem me comunico usam essa forma, a outra metade utiliza `depurar`. Interessante é que as pessoas que utilizam a forma `debugar` também possuem um vocabulário mais americanizado. Quando jogo com eles, escuto verbos como *healar*, *killar*, *ultar*, *startar*, *bootar*, *cheatar* etc. Acho que em poucas gerações teremos um dialeto no qual todas as formas verbais são os verbos ingleses com a primeira conjugação do Português. Isso não me incomoda, estou apenas dizendo :D `</rant>`
- **Popular:** esse verbo foi "aportuguesado" de forma mais apropriada. Não encontrei referências no *Priberam* nem no *Aurélio*, mas essa forma não me incomoda (e dessa vez é serio). Existe um sinônimo que é o verbo `preencher`, mas acho que `popular` carrega um significado a mais - não se trata de preencher no sentido de eliminar um vazio, mas sim no sentido de dar contexto ou propósito.
- **Sortear:** não. Apenas não. Simplesmente não. Toda vez que você fala ou escreve isso, Deus mata um gatinho. Por favor, tenha misericórdia para com os gatinhos.
- **Array:** essa palavra tem diversos significados em Inglês. Cada significado tem uma tradução diferente para o Português. Acho que seria confuso querer traduzir sempre. Além do mais, acho que em praticamente todos os casos se trata de um tipo de dados de uma linguagem. Nesse caso, se quiséssemos traduzir, seríamos pedantes.

Comment: Concordo com o seu ponto de vista na questão do `Array`, é o mesmo que traduzir `String`, `Object` ou `Class`.